# Authorize Attribute and modal dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want show modal window when user clicks on action that requires authentification.
I saw this question and answer:
[ASP.NET MVC Authorize Attribute to launch a modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174713/asp-net-mvc-authorize-attribute-to-launch-a-modal)

I get PopupAuthorizeAttribute from answer and in the Site.Master file wrote:

```
<% if((bool)(ViewData["OpenAuthorizationPopup"] ?? true)) { %>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Login needed")</script> **for test
<% } %>
```

The message shows only when page is loading. But when I click on an action (with PopupAuthorize) then action works anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to `override` [`OnAuthorization()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.onauthorization%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) on your custom `PopupAuthorize` attribute and in their you can redirect to any action of any of your controllers that can return desired `ActionResult` or `JsonResult` for example that you can pop up in a modal.

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(urlHelper.Action("Denied", "Access"));
}
```