# Show popup from ActionFilter if session expires in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-timeout, action-filter, custom-action-filter, onauthorization

We have created a website using mvc where in I have 3 controllers:

```
AccountController
HomeController
ContactController
```

We have written custom Authorization in the ActionFilters wherein we are checking whether the session has expired or not. If the session expires we are redirecting to the login page. This is the code in the ActionFilter:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User;
            var UserProcesses = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserProcesses"] != null ? ((List<string>)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserProcesses"]) : null;
            var currentRequest = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName.ToLower();
            var currentController = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentController))
            {
                switch (currentController.ToLower())
                {
                    case "home":
                        {
                            if (UserProcesses == null)
                            {
                                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                                        new RouteValueDictionary(
                                            new
                                            {
                                                Controller = "Account",
                                                Action = "Login"
                                            })
                                        );
                            }
                break;
         case "contact":
                        {

                            if (UserProcesses == null)
                            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                                        new RouteValueDictionary(
                                            new
                                            {
                                                Controller = "Account",
                                                Action = "Login"
                                            })
                                        );
                            }
                break;

            }
        }
    }
```

This works perfectly i.e. when the session expires and the user clicks on any link on the website, he is redirected to the login page the address of which is

```
http://websitename/Account/Login
```

But now we want to display a popup on the page(whatever page the user is in) which will show the message "That session has expired" and on dismissing that popup, the user is then redirected to the login page.

I am unable to figure out how to call a Jquery popup from the ActionFilter itself. I have searched through many solutions on the web but couldn't find the correct solution to this. Some one suggested to use **HandleUnauthorizedRequest** to call an Action method ([Call RedirectToAction from ActionFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472578/is-it-possible-to-use-redirecttoaction-inside-a-custom-authorizeattribute-clas)). However I am confused whether to use only **HandleUnauthorizedRequest** or use both this and **OnAuthorization** in my code. Can someone please suggest a solution?

**Note:** I have a common View wherein I can keep the html for popup to be used across the website.

Comment: I think this post solves your issue :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174713/asp-net-mvc-authorize-attribute-to-launch-a-modal

Comment: @MariusB YES!!! This solves my issue :) Thanks a lot..Can you please write that as an answer so that I can accept it

Comment: I'm glad it solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was thinking of a solution that uses a variable, and depending on that variable, you would show or not a popup.
I was too lazy to actually write the code, but I've found out a link that describes a solution :

[ASP.NET MVC Authorize Attribute to launch a modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174713/asp-net-mvc-authorize-attribute-to-launch-a-modal)

Answer (score 1):

There is one more way to tackle it i.e. Just go to the `_Layout.cshtml` file and put the below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {          

        var SessionValue = '@Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["YourSessionKey"]';


        if (SessionValue == "") {
            alert("your session is expired please try to Re-login");
            javascript: document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit();
        }
    });
</script>
```

where `logoutForm` is the id of the logout form in `_Layout.cshtml`.