# Authorize Attribute and popup dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I need show popup dialog to authorize clients, i saw this one solution [authorize attribute to launch a modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174713/asp-net-mvc-authorize-attribute-to-launch-a-modal). But this solution show private view with modal dialog, if i click close button of model dialog, i still stay at private view. It's not good, isn't? I think too.

Goal is: When i click to link of private view, we check authorization. If client not authorized we show popup dialog. if client inputted correct login/pass we redirect to private page.

How i can do this?

**PersonalController**

```
public class PersonalController : BaseController
{
    [PopupAuthorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(BaseViewObject);
    }


    [PopupAuthorize]
    public ActionResult PersonalPrice()
    {
        return View(BaseViewObject);
    }
}
```

**PopupAuthorizeAttribute**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class PopupAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private void CacheValidateHandler(HttpContext context, object data, ref HttpValidationStatus validationStatus)
    {
        validationStatus = OnCacheAuthorization(new HttpContextWrapper(context));
    }


    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }


    protected override HttpValidationStatus OnCacheAuthorization(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return base.OnCacheAuthorization(httpContext);
    }
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnAuthorization");
        bool isAuthorized = false;
        if (filterContext == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }
        if (AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext)) {
            HttpCachePolicyBase cache = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
            cache.SetProxyMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0L));
            cache.AddValidationCallback(CacheValidateHandler, null);
            isAuthorized = true;
        }

        filterContext.Controller.ViewData["OpenAuthorizationPopup"] = isAuthorized == false;
    }
 }
```

**_layout**

```
  <!-- other html code -->
  @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false && ((bool)(ViewData["OpenAuthorizationPopup"] ?? false))) { 
    @Html.Partial("_LogInPartial", Model.Auth)
}
```

Comment: `[AuthorizeAttribute]` won't let the request continue if authorization fails, and will instead throw a 401.  How are you using it in your code?

Comment: i add additional informatuin